# Send Ctrl-C to prompt without control button

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard

I use ssh on my phone (for school). Since I obviously don't have a control key, how would I kill a process that's running? I don't have root access.

Comment: What terminal emulator app are you using?

Comment: on android, [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en) provides ctrl/alt/escape keys.

Answer (score 4):

Most of those phone terminal apps have a meta key that lets you prefix a key with <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, whatever you need. Mine has these prefixes at the top of the virtual keyboard. There are plenty to choose from on Google Play/App Store/Windows Store.

Comment: That is true, and mine does actually have one. But out of curiosity is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I saw some apps for android that gave a user a "vim keyboard". It could be used in any context. Don't remember if it had CTRL, but it had ESC.